# Redis, pubsub keyspace notifications on set key, val when expired or deleted

Tags: redis

On https://redis.io/topics/notifications we can read on **Redis Keyspace notificaitons.**

What I am after is ultimately to implement a lock mechanism of some sort.

I am calling redis **SET** with **nx**, **px** with an expiry timeout.

When a key expires, is altered, or deleted I would like to be notified, in order to wake up potential waiters.

I understand I can do something like that using:

```
config set notify-keyspace-events KEA
```

However, this is a global setting and fires for lots and lots of things. Not ideal.

I also am unsure why I have to enable it globally when I am only interested in **certain** **keys**.

Using redis-cli, I currently execute:

```
  redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__key*__:*'
```

And I get a printout of all things happening. Too much really.

A, is there a way to get redis to filter out the key and type for me, for instance:

```
 redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__MY_KEY*__:del'
```

??

Should I be creating a global mechanism for consuming all these messages, and create my own pub/sub mechanism?

Should the latter not already be built in?

Also, is it possible to pubsub without globally enabling redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events KEA ?

Comment: `Ok, I think I am getting closer: __keyspace@0__:mykey`

Comment: But unable to listen to specific set, del, expired events. Only all events.

Comment: Something like I would like to do: 

`redis-cli --csv psubscribe "__keyspace@0__:aaa","expired"` but doesn't work.

Comment: You can just use K instead of KEA if you just want events on that key, but it will return all events because you can't filter based on the published message. So `__keyspace@0__:mykey` is your best bet.